# Sending sine wave values from array to audio output

Tags: c, alsa, trigonometry

Im trying to get a c program to send a sine wave tone to the audio output of my raspberry pi using ALSA
Im generating the buffer of sine wave values but when i send them it doesnt sound like a sine - but like low-mid frequency noise?
I have a dumped the values from the array into a .csv and plotted in excel to verify the sine wave is good
Just wondering have a got stuff fundamentally incorrect in this program, if someone could spot something id be very grateful, thanks

edit: final working code below!!!

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <alsa/pcm.h>
#include <math.h>
#define BUFFER_LEN 48000

static char *device = "default";                       //soundcard
snd_output_t *output = NULL;
float buffer [BUFFER_LEN];


int main(void)
{
    int err;
    int j,k;

    int f = 440;                //frequency
    int fs = 48000;             //sampling frequency

    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_sframes_t frames;


    // ERROR HANDLING

    if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
            printf("Playback open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_set_params(handle,
                                  SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT,
                                  SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED,
                                  1,
                                  48000,
                                  1,
                                  500000)) < 0) {   
            printf("Playback open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


    }

    // SINE WAVE
    printf("Sine tone at %dHz ",f);

        for (k=0; k<BUFFER_LEN; k++){

            buffer[k] = (sin(2*M_PI*f/fs*k));                 //sine wave value generation                        
            }       

        for (j=0; j<5; j++){
            frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, BUFFER_LEN);    //sending values to sound driver
            }

    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have configured the sample format `SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8`, but the actuall buffer contains 32-bit floating-point samples.

Use `SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT`, or define the buffer as an array of `unsigned char`.

Furthermore, you have confused the loop to initialize the `buffer` and the loop to play the data, and many bytes/frames numbers, and `fs` is wrong; you need to use something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; i++)
    buffer [i] = sin(2*M_PI*f/48000*i);  // sine wave value generation

for (i = 0; i < 10 * 48000 / BUFFER_LEN; i++) { // 10 seconds
    frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, BUFFER_LEN);

    if (frames < 0)
        frames = snd_pcm_recover(handle, frames, 0);
    if (frames < 0) {
        printf("snd_pcm_writei failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(frames));
        break;
    }
    if (frames > 0 && frames < BUFFER_LEN)
        printf("Short write (expected %li, wrote %li)\n", BUFFER_LEN, frames);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help - yes i should have spotted that. However, i tried to change the SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8 to SND_PCM_FORMAT_S32 - as my buffer is 32 bit signed numbers? The program compiles but it wont run, just gives a Segmentation Fault? I also tried other syntaxes of SND_PCM_FORMAT, like the float option as you suggested but also gives a segmentaiton fault - any ideas?? thanks!

Comment: Updated – `&buffer[i]` is the wrong place to start if you want to play the entire buffer.

Comment: Hi, sorry, complete c noob here... what do you mean confused the loop to initialize the buffer and the loop to play the data? Also if &buffer[i] is wrong, how should i send this data to the soundcard?? many thanks

Comment: Hi, ive tried the above code you suggested - however when i printf the buffer its just zeros all the way? any idea why that may be? thanks

Comment: This assumes a `float` buffer (`sin` returns values in the range -1..1). If you use integers, you have to scale the result.

Comment: hi, i dont want to use integers, sine is returning values between -1 and 1, and buffer is float so thats why im confused as to why im getting zeros returned for every position in the buffer, first value should be something like 0.1305 ?? thanks

Comment: ok - it seems if i comment out the 2nd FOR loop and run the 1st FOR loop only, then i can see the sine wave values ok for buffer[i] ... so the interaction between the 2 loops is where the problem lies.....